# php - can I get every http request information come to any resource on my domain?

Tags: php

I want to get and log every request that come to any resource on my domain.
I know how to get it if the requested resource is the php file. and that is by inserting the piece of code that will log the `$_REQUEST` information into every php file on my website, and save this information on a file or db..etc.

but I don't know how to know throw PHP if someone requested another resource (e.g: images, js scripts,...etc).

**1- Is** there a PHP way to know if someone requested other resources than PHP files?

**2- Is** there a another way to log the requests to my php files better than inserting the logging code into every php file?

Comment: What about the apache access-log?

Comment: @tkausl I didn't know it before, but It seems it is the only way, I will give it a look. thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this from PHP if the execution does not go through the *logger script*. But luckily for you, Apache already saves all the access logs. Just search in the apache2.conf (or httpd.conf) file to see where are the access logs stored.